# I have this problem in Xcode saying "Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String'"

Tags: swift

Here is the struct:

```swift
import Foundation

struct Question {
    let text : String
    //Multiple choice questions have multiple answers, an Array of Strings would work for our quiz data.
    let answers : String
    //Look at the data in the quiz array, there is a seperate string that is the correctAnswer.
    let rightAnswer: String

    //The initialiser needs to be updated to match the new multiple choice quiz data. 
    init(q: String, a: String, correctAnswer: String) {
        text = q
        answers = a
        rightAnswer = correctAnswer
    }
}
```

And here is the code with the problem:

```swift
let quiz = [
    Question(q: "Which is the largest organ in the human body?", a: ["Heart", "Skin", "Large Intestine"], correctAnswer: "Skin"),
    Question(q: "Five dollars is worth how many nickels?", a: ["25", "50", "100"], correctAnswer: "100"),
    Question(q: "What do the letters in the GMT time zone stand for?", a: ["Global Meridian Time", "Greenwich Mean Time", "General Median Time"], correctAnswer: "Greenwich Mean Time"),
    Question(q: "What is the French word for 'hat'?", a: ["Chapeau", "Écharpe", "Bonnet"], correctAnswer: "Chapeau"),
    Question(q: "In past times, what would a gentleman keep in his fob pocket?", a: ["Notebook", "Handkerchief", "Watch"], correctAnswer: "Watch"),
    Question(q: "How would one say goodbye in Spanish?", a: ["Au Revoir", "Adiós", "Salir"], correctAnswer: "Adiós"),
    Question(q: "Which of these colours is NOT featured in the logo for Google?", a: ["Green", "Orange", "Blue"], correctAnswer: "Orange"),
    Question(q: "What alcoholic drink is made from molasses?", a: ["Rum", "Whisky", "Gin"], correctAnswer: "Rum"),
    Question(q: "What type of animal was Harambe?", a: ["Panda", "Gorilla", "Crocodile"], correctAnswer: "Gorilla"),
    Question(q: "Where is Tasmania located?", a: ["Indonesia", "Australia", "Scotland"], correctAnswer: "Australia")
]
```

I looked for a solution on Stack Overflow but nothing was working so I am desperate to make this code work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you were missing some square backets in your structure.

```
struct Question {
    
    let text: String
    //Multiple choice questions have multiple answers, an Array of Strings would work for our quiz data.
    let answers : [String] // <- Here
    //Look at the data in the quiz array, there is a seperate string that is the correctAnswer.
    let correctAnswer: String
    //The initialiser needs to be updated to match the new multiple choice quiz data.
    init(text: String, answers: [String], correctAnswer: String) { // <- Here
        self.text = text
        self.answers = answers
        self.correctAnswer = correctAnswer
        
    }
}
```